# How to know when file downloading is finished?

Tags: node.js, express, download

I need to get an user download his file and remove it after response get finished:

```
app.get('/download/:file', function (req, res) {
   var filePath = '/files/' + req.param('file');
   res.download(file);

   fs.unlink(filePath); 
});
```

In the code above fs.unlink could invoked early than res.download will get finished.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the callback in the download api:

```
res.download(filePath, req.param('file'), function(err){
  //CHECK FOR ERROR
  fs.unlink(filePath);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but according documentation: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.download "handle error, keep in mind the response may be partially-sent so check res.headerSent" What does it mean?

Comment: For your use-case, it should not matter.  This is more about sending a response to the client.  This is basically saying it is possible that the headers were already sent as 200 as well as other portions of the response, so you will not be able to send an HTTP error code or completely control the response content in the event the download fails.

Comment: Thanks but `unlink` is an asynchronous and it will trigger error "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function". Switched to `unlinkSync` and it works great for me.

Answer (score 5):

```
res.download(filePath, req.param('file'), function(err){
  //CHECK FOR ERROR
  fs.unlink(filePath);
});
```